# take off (meaning in context)

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

what's the meaning of "take off" in this context:

"She started ballet when she was young. She took off. Then progressively she started other types of dances."

Does it mean, she took a break or does it mean she became successful?

Thank you.

Comment: The second: she showed good achievements.

Comment: [AHDEL](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/take+off) (under what they call _phrasal verbs_. Which sense do you think applies here? Remember it's an intransitive usage.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth "AHDEL"? I can't find any non-pejorative meaning.  Am I missing something simple?

Comment: American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language, Fifth Edition. Copyright © 2011 by Houghton Mifflin Harcourt Publishing Company. Published by Houghton Mifflin Harcourt Publishing Company. All rights reserved. It occupies the 'first 3.5 pages' of the hyperlink given. **take off** 
6c. To achieve success or popularity: a new movie that really took off. Collins also list this (as sense 6) for 'take off' below AHDEL.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth You should post your comment(s) as the answer.

Comment: @pyobum On ELU, it would be considered general reference and thus not merit an 'answer'. I'm only really interested in (1) having fun with the intricacies of English (2) preserving the integrity of ELU in particular (though that's important on all academic websites) (3) helping if I can (4) learning where I can (5) thinking up worse puns than Erik Kowal. Please feel free to post what I've written as an 'answer' if that is preferable here on ELL.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I hear ya. I just thought you might want to pick up the reputation points. I would have posted a similar answer to your comment, but personally I don't feel right posting an answer someone's already given in a comment. And I'll be keeping an eye out for puns from you and Erik going forward. Cheers.

Comment: What is the source for the quotation?  If the author is a native speaker of English who writes carefully, I agree with [A.Beth](http://ell.stackexchange.com/users/15827)'s interpretation.  If the author is not a native speaker, or if the author is not careful, then I would expect the author meant "She took time off."

Answer (score 2):

In this context, it means she "took off like a rocket" -- she learned ballet quickly and became good at it quickly.

If she spent time not-dancing, it would be, "She took a break" explicitly.

In some contexts, "took off" could mean "ran away," but this one is pretty clear that it's referring to taking off like a rocket. (Or a plane, or something else that goes quickly into the air.)

Comment: (+1) However 'like a rocket' is perhaps extreme. I would rather say this is a milder metaphor for flight.  A young bird leaves the nest and flies for the first time. It soon becomes an expert aviator.

Answer (score 1):

> She started ballet when she was young.
>   She took off.

Here in this sentence *took off* means that she became successful and popular.

To know more about *take off* you can refer [here](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/take+off)